# Puzzling behavior of ItoProcess with Abs

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Hi I am simulating a Fisher-Wright diffusion, it works

```
\[Mu] = ( # (1 - #)) &; \[Sigma] = (# (1 - #)/4) &;

FW = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[Mu][t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Sqrt[\[Sigma][t]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1/10}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];

path = RandomFunction[FW //. ca, {0., 10, 0.01 }, 6];

lp = ListLinePlot[%]
```

but the negative values look suspicious (this could be investigated by Feller's boundary classification, but first thought is to  add Abs under the square root, and hell breaks loose)

```
FW = ItoProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[Mu][t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Sqrt[Abs[\[Sigma][t]]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1/10}, t, 
   w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];

path = RandomFunction[FW //. ca, {0., 10, 0.01 }, 6];

lp = ListLinePlot[%]
```

Comment: Expression for `ca` is needed.

Comment: Do you want `\[Mu][t]` and `\[Sigma][t]`, or `\[Mu][x[t]]` and `\[Sigma][x[t]]`?

Comment: Thanks, Chris K. Indeed, I was solving wrong equation. The results  with and without abs are very plausible and quick now :)